# NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'name' is defined

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying a very basic example. I tried to see other stack overflow answers, but couldn't solve this problem. I am new to this space, let me know if I left out anything.

Here is my error log :

> Dec 11, 2017 8:40:20 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
>   INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [BeanDefinition.xml]
>   Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'MySpringBeanWithDepenency' is defined
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:638)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1159)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:282)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:973)
>       at model.main.Main.main(Main.java:18)

which clearly says it cannot find the MySpringBeanWithDepenency

Here is my BeanDefinition.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="model.testbean" />
<context:component-scan base-package="model.writer" />
```

this is my main class :

```
package model.main;

/**
 * Created by barora on 12/10/2017.
 */

import org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

import model.testbean.MySpringBeanWithDepenency;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
                "BeanDefinition.xml");
        BeanFactory factory = context;
        MySpringBeanWithDepenency test = (MySpringBeanWithDepenency) factory.getBean("MySpringBeanWithDepenency");
        test.run();
    }
}
```

this is my MySpringBeanWithDepenency

```
package model.testbean;

/**
 * Created by barora on 12/10/2017.
 */

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import model.writer.IWriter;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;


@Service
public class MySpringBeanWithDepenency {

    private IWriter writer;

    @Autowired
    public void setWriter(IWriter writer){
        this.writer = writer;
    }

    public void run(){
        String s = "This is my test";
        writer.writer(s);
    }
}
```

this is my folder structure :

[image]

Comment: You've included `import`s in your quoted code, but not `package`. Does your class file begin with `package model.testbean;`?

Comment: By the way, every time I see `depenency` instead of `dependency`, it jolts me out of being able to concentrate on the code.

Comment: I added the code with package. Regarding the depenency, the world is imperfect my friend. You'll have to live with and die with this great sorrow.

Comment: Well, one day you'll mis-spell a variable name, and the person who knows the answer won't read your question because of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to debug adding:

```
System.out.println("Bean names: " + Arrays.toString(context.getBeanNamesForType(MySpringBeanWithDependency.class)));
```

If this prints an empty list, then you have an issue with your classpath scanning. If it prints a name, then that's a name you can use to get the bean.

Alternatively, instead of `factory.getBean(String name)` use `factory.getBean(MySpringBeanWithDependency.class)`, so that you don't need to know what name Spring has given your bean.

Comment: you mean depenency here? and not dependency

Comment: I want to upvote your answer for getBeanNamesForType, except that I had to use context instead of factory and it gave me weird value :

Bean names: [Ljava.lang.String;@51e2adc7

Comment: Fixed both. This raises a point - you don't need your `BeanFactory factory = context` - you can just use `context.getBean()` directly.

Comment: I wrote it as `dependency` in the hope that you'd propagate the spelling correction through the rest of your code.

Answer (score 1):

Try  `MySpringBeanWithDepenency test = (MySpringBeanWithDepenency) factory.getBean(MySpringBeanWithDepenency.class);`

**EDITED**

So I've recreated code using given project structure. It works with exception that I've used following code for `IWriter`

```
  package model.writer;

    public interface IWriter {

        void writer(String s);
    }
```

and for implementation

```
package model.writer;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class NiceWriter implements IWriter {
    public void writer(String s) {

    }
}
```

**EDITED 2**
If you want to have two implementation for `IWriter` interface and both supposed to be spring managed beans you need to help spring container to decide which one you want it to autowire. Use `@Qualifier` for this. See [tutorial](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-autowire) for details

Comment: Sorry I didn't remove quotes for class after converting it to the .class format.
How can I use string format there? I have marked the answer as correct though.

Comment: @BhavyaArora for what reasons you want to use string format there?

Answer (score 0):

The default bean name is mySpringBeanWithDepenency with "m"
you should use

```
MySpringBeanWithDepenency test = (MySpringBeanWithDepenency)factory.getBean("mySpringBeanWithDepenency");
```